# Get part of a string

Tags: string, coldfusion

I need to get part of a string from an audit string.

I am currently using mid, but i am fairly new to ColdFusion and wondered if there was a better way.

The string looks like this

```
"1990-12-01+10:40:02,username,description"
```

I need to get all entries for a month, currently using mid, is this the best approach

```
mid(me, 6, 2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the string will always be in that format what you have made will be fine.  This will also work:

```
<cfscript>
    myString = "1990-12-01+10:40:02,username,description";
    writeOutput(listGetAt(myString,2,"-"));
</cfscript>
```

Comment: +1 you can also change the delimiter to "-+:" which means all those fields will be separated and you can access them by position.